# How can I run commands in a docker container when the process for the main command is not running or has ended?

Tags: docker

**Context**

Usually, I can set up a command for a container. E.g. if I create a container based on python 2.7 and running django code, my command would come like this:

> $ docker container create --name my-django-proj -v path/to/my/proj:/project -ti python:2.7 "cd /project && python manage.py runserver"

(please this is just an example! I know I could use gunicorn instead, and so, but the topic is not about django specifically, but docker. Also, *Let's assume there is an actual Django project in path/to/my/proj*)

This command has a caveat: If I want to perform maintenance tasks in my Django server, and have to kill the process, the container will stop.

So, something I thought is: *Make the container execute bash, and once in bash, execute manually those two commands*. Indeed, that option serves me well. I can do it:

> $ docker container create --name my-django-proj -v path/to/my/proj:/project -ti python:2.7 bash

And...

> $ docker container start -i

And...

> # cd /project
>   # python manage.py runserver

And if somehow I have to perform maintenance tasks (specially the first time! when no requirements will be yet installed and I must manually run packages installs with -in this example- `pip`), I can kill the server, do stuff, and then restart the server.

If I don't want to be in front of the console and want to run it as daemon, I can remove the -i flag, add the -d flag and later send commands to start and stop the server like this:

> docker exec -it my-django-proj cd /project && python manage.py runserver

Since the main command is bash, I know the container is alive until I stop it.

But my issue is: I'd like that command (this two commands) be run right inside the bash command, and when those commands end (in this case: when the django server is stopped), *keep the bash alive* so the container can be still running and can perform more tasks interactively or via `docker exec`.

Briefly: I know how to do this manually - How can I do this automatically?

**Edit** I found that I can use `bash "cd /project ; python manage.py runserver ; bash"`. Is there a way to do that without having a second bash process?

Comment: If you just add an extra command for keeping it alive is OK? For example: `docker container create --name my-django-proj -v path/to/my/proj:/project -ti python:2.7 sh -c "cd /project && python manage.py runserver" && tail -f /dev/null` (note that I added th `sc -c`. I added because of the slashes `/`)

Comment: I'll try it now...

Comment: It works well if I want to run it as daemon, but not if I want to run it interactively. In this latter case, there is no console I can access